# Method of determining the 3 peaks of a Cd-109 Gamma Ray Spectrum

Tags: photons, spectroscopy, gamma-rays

I took a full spectrum of Cd-109 and the result was a peak around 5 keV, a peak around 22 keV, and a peak around 87.85 keV. I know that there are actually supposed to be two peaks around 22 keV, but my machine apparently didn't quite have the resolution to show this.

My main question is this: How do I determine what types of events caused these peaks? My general understanding is that these peaks are the result of some sort of events between the incoming gamma rays and the electrons of the NaI(Tl) scintillation crystal.

Comment: So, are you asking about what the Cd is doing, or how scintillators work?

Comment: @JonCuster I'm asking about what the peaks mean

Comment: Everything you want to know about nuclei can be found at https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/ - search on 109Cd to get the assigned gamma levels.